# Is there a way to export Excel 2010 files into a Wordpress database as ACTUAL Wordpress pages?

Tags: microsoft-excel, wordpress

This is a strange question, but I run a magazine in wordpress where I really want more control offline for making a page look right, rather than mucking about with it online.   (Long story but, as much as I love the idea of switching to Drupal, the number of data tables used by Drupal quickly exceeds my JustHost quota, which is why we need to stick with Wordpress for now.)

As I've been working with Excel 2010, it seems like it would be possible to create a post  creation tool that could format things the way I want them from a form layout setup and, then, using some third party solution, upload it into a Wordpress database.  Has anyone had any success with this?  (If so, is there a solution for formatting images?)

You can also see the overall layout of the [magazine](http://www.microfilmmaker.com/wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You could export the Wordpress database from phpMyAdmin, open the SQL file in a text editor, and examine the format of Posts and Pages.

You could then replicate the database table layout for Posts and Pages in Excel, produce your Posts and Pages in Excel, and then export from Excel as a .CSV, ensuring you give each Post or Page a unique post id.

Then import the CSV file into phpMyAdmin.

Caveat: you'd need to ensure you have the right INSERT statements.  You can examine the SQL file for how to do this.